# How to select rows if first of them will be randomized and the rest should be ordered by criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

My database table 'hotels' has a following structure:

```
id       (int)
name     (varchar)
is_top   (tinyint)
price    (smallint)
```

That table has a following data:

```
id|name|is_top|price
 1|Vean|1     |2.05
 2|Gret|0     |5.10
 3|Kapa|0     |0.72
 4|Yeny|0     |0.39
 5|Lena|1     |0.95
```

How to select rows which will be ordered by 'is_top' (descending and randomized) and the rest of them ordered by price ascending.

I tried a following query but not success:

```
SELECT id, name, is_top, price 
FROM `hotels` 
ORDER BY IF (is_top=1, RAND(), price) ASC
```

EDIT:
Expected result should be:

```
id|name|is_top|price
 5|Lena|1     |0.95
 1|Vean|1     |2.05
 4|Yeny|0     |0.39
 3|Kapa|0     |0.72
 2|Gret|0     |5.10
```

First two rows (where is_top=1) should be always randomized.

Comment: Can you show how you want the sample data you've given sorted? I'm not sure I'm following...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `order by` clause should have two columns - the first is `is_top`, and the second is a calculated `case` expression - `rand()` when `is_top` is `1` or `price` otherwise:

```
SELECT   id, name, is_top, price 
FROM     `hotels` 
ORDER BY is_top DESC, CASE is_top WHEN 1 THEN RAND() ELSE price END ASC
```